# My posts are not making it to the database, any ideas?

Tags: php, html

I'm following a tutorial by mmtuts on youtube to show how to post comments to a myphpadmin database.  All of my code is exactly the same as his, but I'm working from a different starting point becuase I already had a website I was working on and I just wanted to add the new code.

Basically, the video showed the code working flawlessly and my posts do not show up in the database like his did.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pPGOF5MI4U

".setComments($conn)." on the second document of code is blue instead of white like in the video.

```
<?php  
    require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="This is an example of a meta description.  This will often show up in search results.">
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>TAG</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
        <div id="headerContainer">
            <?php 
                if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
                    $id = $_SESSION['userID'];
                    $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileimg WHERE userid='$id'";
                    $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
                    while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {      
                        if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
                            $filename = "profilepics/profile".$id."*";
                            $fileinfo = glob($filename);
                            $fileext = explode(".", $fileinfo[0]);
                            $fileactualext = $fileext[1];
                            echo "<div class=userPicture><img src='profilepics/profile".$id.".".$fileactualext."?".mt_rand()."'></div>";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<div class='userPicture'><img src='profilepics/noUser.png'></div>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo    '
                            <div class="userName">'. $_SESSION['userUserName'] .'</div>

                            <div id="logoutForm">
                                <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
                                    <button type="Submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <div class="upload">
                                <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input type="file" name="file">
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit">Profile Image</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            ';
                }
                else {
                    echo    '
                            <div class="userPicture"><img src="profilepics/noUser.png"></div>
                            <div class="userName">You are not logged in!</div>

                            <div id="loginForm">
                                <form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
                                    <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Username/E-mail">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    <button type="Submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <div id="signupForm">
                                <a href="signup.php">or Signup</a>
                            </div>

                            ';
                }
            ?>          
        </div>
```

```
<?php
    require "header.php";
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    include 'includes/comments.inc.php';
?>
    <div class="homeBody">
        <p>Starting Filler</p>
        <p>-</p>
        <p>-</p>
        <p>-</p>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
            <source src="videos/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <?php
        echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
            <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
            <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
        </form>";
        ?>
```

```
<?php 

function setComments($conn) {
    if (isset($POST['commentSubmit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "thisisnotmyactualpassword";
$dBName = "tagloginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

All I want is for the posts to make it into the database.

Comment: Document 1 - Header

Document 2 - Index

Document 3 - comments.inc.php

Document 4 - dbh.inc.php

Comment: Please discard that tutorial link. It is a terrible tutorial if it is teaching this way. This is open to SQL injections. Can you clarify what you mean by `code is blue instead of white`? That sounds like a CSS issue.

Comment: I am using the sublime text editor and the text within his video appears white instead of blue(not on the website but inside the code).

I am aware of the hacking possibilities within this tutorial but the way he teaches slowly sets up how to fix previous problems.  It's more of a beginner series.

Comment: There's no point in teaching/learning the wrong way to do something. It sounds like you are talking about syntax highlighting in Sublime. That is more an IDE question than a PHP/HTML question. I'd tag Sublime as well, I'm not familiar with that editor.

Comment: are you getting any errors or inserting wrong data ?

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump()  $result?   Unless you say what is going wrong it is hard to know which of the many possible places things could be going wrong are.  Also echo $sql and run the query directly in phpmyadmin. Does it work as expected?

Comment: Are you sure that you have successfully established connection? Try to echo information in setComment() so that you know what is really happening

Comment: I am not getting any errors and I do not think I am using the wrong data.

Comment: `if (!$conn) {
    echo "connection error";
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}` printing a message to know whether there is a connection problem with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the "_" in $_POST on the 3rd page of code

Answer (score 0):

Try making a separate PHP-file and have your action attribute inside the form tag point to it. Right now it looks like you are running the function in the action attribute. In the PHP-file you can run your PHP function and write the PHP you need.

EX:

```
<form method='POST' action="includes/comments.php">
```